# return computed Mono from completing Flux

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflux, reactor

I am new to spring webflux and have a problem with aggregating a flux to a Mono.

ProductController has a method `Flux<Product> get(List<UUID> ids)` returning a Stream of Products for a given list of ids. When all products have been fetched the flux completes.

Aggregator fetches a list of products, computes a new ProductAggregateDTO from the stream and sends it to an accountingService, which then processes them and assigns an UUID to the accounting process.

```
class Aggregator {
  Mono<UUID> process(List<UUID> ids) {
    ProductAggregateDTO adto = new ProductAggregateDTO();
    productAdapter.getProducts(ids)
      .doOnNext(e -> {
        adto.consume(e);
      })
      .doOnComplete(() -> {
        Mono<UUID> processId = accountAdapter.process(adto);
      })
      .subscribe();

  }
}
```

I want to return processId from the process function. I don't think thats a big problem. But I can not find how.

Thanks for your help!

Kind Regards,
Andreas

Comment: Note that your code would be easier to read as `.doOnNext(adto::consume)`.

Comment: Instead of `doOnComplete` use the `then` operator.

Comment: Thanks for your help, `then` did the trick. If you post an answer I will accept it as the solution.

Comment: I appreciate Toerktumlare's help, too. Thank you. :)